# absence of clojure.core in non-default namespaces within lein repl

Tags: clojure, leiningen

In a lein repl, whenever I do

```clj
(in-ns 'some-namespace-other-than-name.core)
```

clojure.core is not included by default.

To explain, initially I found myself getting caught by this like so

```clj
db.core=> (in-ns 'db.seed)
#object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x12738ef5 "db.seed"]
db.seed=> (use 'environ.core)
Syntax error compiling at (form-init7774277424301430706.clj:1:1).
Unable to resolve symbol: use in this context
```

I just found how to fix this:

```clj
db.seed=> (clojure.core/use 'clojure.core)
nil
db.seed=> (use 'environ.core)
nil
```

My question is, it seems that clojure.core is included automatically in the namespace myapp.core, but not in any other namespaces  i might switch to in the repl.
(yet, obviously those namespaces ***do*** have access to clojure.core when i run the program from the core namespace).

Is that just a leiningen default?

Wondering what piece of understanding or usage I'm missing here.

Is it that when we run a program, only myapp.core needs access to clojure.core, and the namespaces your .core will utilise do not themselves need access to clojure.core, because they are, when executed, merely imports into your app's .core?  Hence switching to some other namespace to run things is in essence a bit artificial?

I looked at the docs for the [:main key in project.clj](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj) but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: There is also `refer-clojure`, see the explanation here: https://clojure.org/guides/repl/navigating_namespaces#_switching_to_an_existing_namespace_with_in_ns

Comment: Interesting. So issuing `(clojure.core/refer-clojure)` seems to have similar effect to issuing `(clojure.core/use 'clojure.core)`, when in a namespace where core is absent.

Comment: If of interest, the method I've been using when direct at the repl is to issue like `(require 'db.series :verbose :reload)` to reload a file I've been working on, then simply call functions in that other (now reloaded) namespace always by fully qualifying them, like `(pprint (db.series/app-state ...))`, i.e. not bothering to switch to the other namespace at all. At least this works without surprises.

Answer (score 3):

See these two references in ClojureDocs.org:

- https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/in-ns
- https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/ns

I think it's easier to just use `ns`.

There is also a nice [blog posting by 8thlight](https://8thlight.com/blog/colin-jones/2010/12/05/clojure-libs-and-namespaces-require-use-import-and-ns.html).  You should also be sure to read [How to ns](https://stuartsierra.com/2016/clojure-how-to-ns.html).

---

**Example**

Suppose I have a main ns `demo.core` and a testing ns `tst.demo.core`.  I access from the repl:

```
~/expr/demo > lein repl
demo.core=> (in-ns 'tst.demo.core)
#object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x6a2b14a1 "tst.demo.core"]
tst.demo.core=> (use 'demo.core)
Syntax error compiling at (/tmp/form-init10207825906790622351.clj:1:1).
Unable to resolve symbol: use in this context
```

So the above shows the problem, that `clojure.core` is not referred into the ns by `in-ns`.

Alternatively, just use `ns`:

```
~/expr/demo > lein repl
demo.core=> (ns tst.demo.core)       ; note absence of single-quote!
nil
tst.demo.core=> (use 'demo.core)     ; all clojure.core is automatically refered
nil
```

Comment: thanks but i don't think this really answers the question yet

Comment: oh, thanks!.  When you first mentioned to use `ns`, it didn't dawn on me to actually enter it in the repl; i only thought of it as a thing in a src file.